# Scanf Dont scan char 2nd time while in a loop, any ideas?

Tags: c

```
    n=10;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        random = 1 + rand() % 3;  
        printf("\n\nIzdari savu izveli ==>");
        scanf("%c", &zime);
        if( zime=='a' )
            printf("\nTu uzliki AKMENI");
        else if( zime=='s' )
            printf("\nTu uzliki SKERES");
         else if( zime=='p' )
            printf("\nTu uzliki PAPIRU");

        if( random==1 )
            printf("\nDators uzlika AKMENI");
        else if( random==2 )
            printf("\nDators uzlika SKERES");
        else if( random==3 )
            printf("\nDators uzlika PAPIRU");

        if( random==1&&zime=='a' || random==2 && zime=='s' || random==3 && zime=='p')
        printf("\n\nNeizskirts!!!");
    else if( random==1&&zime=='p' || random==2&&zime=='a' || random==3&&zime=='s' )
        printf("\n\nTu Uzvareji!!!");
    else if( random==1&&zime=='s' || random==2&&zime=='p' || random==3&&zime=='a' )
        printf("\n\nTu Zaudeji!!!");
    getch();
    }
```

Why when loop starts 2nd time it just skips `scanf`,
and jumps to `if( random==1 )`, 
and then jumps back to `scanf` and let u scanf a char?

Output looks like

[image: a]

It is just rock paper scizors game, but in other language.

Comment: This question as been asked like 2 minutes ago!

Answer (score 1):

There is a newline character `\n`  at the end of first input and that is picked by the `scanf()` during the second loop.

Chnage your scanf as :

```
scanf(" %c", &zime);
```